# Have a link that uses window.history by default but still supports opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs, browser-history

Say my website is `example.com`. On it, I have the following link: `<a href="?foo=bar">Click here</a>`, which upon clicking should take the user to `example.com/?foo=bar`.

What I want is, by default, the link should use `window.history` when clicked. In particular, it will use

```js
window.history.pushState({"foo": "bar"}, "", "?foo=bar")
```

However, if the user e.g. "middle clicks" or right clicks and says "Open in New Tab", then the anchor link should act as normal and just open in a new tab (without erroneously triggering the `pushState` in the current tab). This should also preferably work with non-standard methods of opening a link in a new tab, such as using the Vimium web extension.

Is there some standard way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a demo. `href` is used for the right clicks and `e.preventDefault()` is for the default action

```
    <div>
        <a href="?foo=bar" id="testLink" >Jump</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.querySelector('#testLink').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                window.history.pushState({"foo": "bar"}, "", "?foo=bar")
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Supports middle click as well, and works mostly perfectly. But, for example, Vimium's "open in new tab" command doesn't work with it (just tested it myself). Vimium's "open in new tab" command just uses the default behavior when clicking that link. Any way to fix this maybe...?

Comment: What do you expect  about Vimium's  "open in new tab"

Comment: Vimium's "open in new tab" command should open the link in a new tab. However, with your code, that command doesn't work properly, and simply clicks the link normally and uses history.pushState. I'm asking if there is any modified version of your code that will play nice with Vimium and have the "open in new tab" command work properly...?

Comment: My Chrome and Firefox work properly. What's is your browser? I'll try it

Comment: I'm using the latest firefox (78.0.2, Windows 10) and Vimium. Your code works fine with middle click and everything. It's just that Vimium's "open in new tab" command isn't working as it should, it's just treating it like a normal click. Does your vimium not exhibit that behavior?